# Rectangle clustering

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I am trying to perform clustering of rectangles where number of clusters is unknown.
Below is an image generated programmatically as well as coordinates of the rectangles.
[image: Rectangles]

Below is code in Python to reproduce the output:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

width = 1024
height = 768
im = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

coords = [[392, 0, 441, 62], [889, 106, 958, 146], [144, 215, 184, 299], [224, 44, 288, 62], [219, 243, 243, 277], [760, 450, 847, 547], [390, 311, 399, 351], [439, 232, 520, 274], [72, 438, 129, 506], [64, 177, 151, 207], [758, 160, 828, 228], [310, 543, 314, 587], [300, 215, 310, 271], [787, 310, 850, 332], [63, 198, 86, 276], [372, 432, 409, 448], [235, 121, 302, 217], [140, 614, 216, 643], [160, 203, 168, 244], [364, 645, 394, 708], [294, 219, 299, 294], [101, 215, 119, 251], [776, 65, 792, 151], [421, 608, 447, 659], [127, 183, 189, 196], [350, 114, 439, 140], [134, 600, 207, 686], [55, 126, 148, 224], [159, 130, 239, 219], [705, 114, 743, 164], [824, 601, 893, 620], [916, 541, 966, 557], [82, 251, 178, 324], [216, 317, 235, 349], [806, 443, 898, 483], [297, 618, 320, 659], [887, 213, 929, 256], [17, 117, 109, 182], [755, 233, 818, 287], [165, 392, 215, 463], [202, 256, 248, 308], [61, 499, 103, 595], [163, 182, 200, 268], [167, 143, 257, 243], [3, 468, 99, 549], [126, 51, 129, 112], [24, 63, 113, 67], [830, 555, 924, 585], [881, 297, 918, 356], [917, 226, 998, 295], [59, 148, 59, 156], [56, 16, 82, 113]]

for coord in coords:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = coord
    draw.rectangle((x1, y1, x2, y2), fill=(192, 192, 192), outline=(122, 122, 122))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

im.save('./1.png',)
```

Is it possible to detect number of clusters automatically ?

If so, could you please provide minimal working example for clustering such data ?

Comment: Im assuming you are trying to cluster on coordinate location, not shape size or something like that

Comment: Re: @pastaleg Yes, I am trying to cluster based on location. Shape will always be a rectangle

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for something like this

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

width = 1024
height = 768
im = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

im2 = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), (255, 255, 255))
draw2 = ImageDraw.Draw(im2)

im3 = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), (255, 255, 255))
draw3 = ImageDraw.Draw(im3)

im4 = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), (255, 255, 255))
draw4 = ImageDraw.Draw(im4)


coords = [[392, 0, 441, 62], [889, 106, 958, 146], [144, 215, 184, 299], [224, 44, 288, 62], [219, 243, 243, 277], [760, 450, 847, 547], [390, 311, 399, 351], [439, 232, 520, 274], [72, 438, 129, 506], [64, 177, 151, 207], [758, 160, 828, 228], [310, 543, 314, 587], [300, 215, 310, 271], [787, 310, 850, 332], [63, 198, 86, 276], [372, 432, 409, 448], [235, 121, 302, 217], [140, 614, 216, 643], [160, 203, 168, 244], [364, 645, 394, 708], [294, 219, 299, 294], [101, 215, 119, 251], [776, 65, 792, 151], [421, 608, 447, 659], [127, 183, 189, 196], [350, 114, 439, 140], [134, 600, 207, 686], [55, 126, 148, 224], [159, 130, 239, 219], [705, 114, 743, 164], [824, 601, 893, 620], [916, 541, 966, 557], [82, 251, 178, 324], [216, 317, 235, 349], [806, 443, 898, 483], [297, 618, 320, 659], [887, 213, 929, 256], [17, 117, 109, 182], [755, 233, 818, 287], [165, 392, 215, 463], [202, 256, 248, 308], [61, 499, 103, 595], [163, 182, 200, 268], [167, 143, 257, 243], [3, 468, 99, 549], [126, 51, 129, 112], [24, 63, 113, 67], [830, 555, 924, 585], [881, 297, 918, 356], [917, 226, 998, 295], [59, 148, 59, 156], [56, 16, 82, 113]]

centers = []

for coord in coords:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = coord
    draw.rectangle((x1, y1, x2, y2), fill=(192, 192, 192), outline=(122, 122, 122))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    c = [(x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2]
    centers.append(c)
    draw2.point((c[0], c[1]), fill = 0)
    draw2.ellipse((c[0]-2, c[1]-2, c[0]+2, c[1]+2), outline=(255, 0 , 0))

im.save('./1.png',)
im2.save('./2.png',)

x = np.array(centers)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans.fit(x)

print(kmeans.cluster_centers_)

print(kmeans.labels_)

for c,label, cord in zip(centers, kmeans.labels_, coords):
    draw3.point((c[0], c[1]), fill = 0)
    if label==0:
        draw3.ellipse((c[0]-5, c[1]-5, c[0]+5, c[1]+5), outline=(255, 0 , 0))
        draw4.rectangle((cord[0], cord[1], cord[2], cord[3]), fill=(255, 0, 0), outline=(122, 122, 122))
    elif label==1:
        draw3.ellipse((c[0]-5, c[1]-5, c[0]+5, c[1]+5), outline=(0, 255 , 0))
        draw4.rectangle((cord[0], cord[1], cord[2], cord[3]), fill=(0, 255, 0), outline=(122, 122, 122))
    else:
        draw3.ellipse((c[0]-5, c[1]-5, c[0]+5, c[1]+5), outline=(0, 0 , 255))
        draw4.rectangle((cord[0], cord[1], cord[2], cord[3]), fill=(0, 0, 255), outline=(122, 122, 122))

im3.save("./3.png")
im4.save("./4.png")
```

I found the center point of rectangles and used centers as rectangle positions then kmeans to group them up now using same you can even color the rectangles

In kmeans you can set number of clusters to be created

It also contains code for the center point representation images as well not attached

[image]

**[Update] Added Silhouette Score as metric for optimizing cluster count**

I added Silhouette Score calculation, it will run on multiple cluster number and give a value between 0 and 1 describing how well distinguished our clusters are

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score

coords = [[392, 0, 441, 62], [889, 106, 958, 146], [144, 215, 184, 299], [224, 44, 288, 62], [219, 243, 243, 277], [760, 450, 847, 547], [390, 311, 399, 351], [439, 232, 520, 274], [72, 438, 129, 506], [64, 177, 151, 207], [758, 160, 828, 228], [310, 543, 314, 587], [300, 215, 310, 271], [787, 310, 850, 332], [63, 198, 86, 276], [372, 432, 409, 448], [235, 121, 302, 217], [140, 614, 216, 643], [160, 203, 168, 244], [364, 645, 394, 708], [294, 219, 299, 294], [101, 215, 119, 251], [776, 65, 792, 151], [421, 608, 447, 659], [127, 183, 189, 196], [350, 114, 439, 140], [134, 600, 207, 686], [55, 126, 148, 224], [159, 130, 239, 219], [705, 114, 743, 164], [824, 601, 893, 620], [916, 541, 966, 557], [82, 251, 178, 324], [216, 317, 235, 349], [806, 443, 898, 483], [297, 618, 320, 659], [887, 213, 929, 256], [17, 117, 109, 182], [755, 233, 818, 287], [165, 392, 215, 463], [202, 256, 248, 308], [61, 499, 103, 595], [163, 182, 200, 268], [167, 143, 257, 243], [3, 468, 99, 549], [126, 51, 129, 112], [24, 63, 113, 67], [830, 555, 924, 585], [881, 297, 918, 356], [917, 226, 998, 295], [59, 148, 59, 156], [56, 16, 82, 113]]
centers = []

for coord in coords:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = coord
    c = [(x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2]
    centers.append(c)

# Vector with center coordinates
x = np.array(centers)

bestScore = -1
idx=-1

for i in range (2, 10):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, random_state=10)
    kmeans.fit(x)
    silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(x, kmeans.labels_)
    print("For n_clusters =", i,
          "The average silhouette_score is :", silhouette_avg)
    if silhouette_avg > bestScore:
        bestScore=silhouette_avg
        idx=i

print("Best score :", bestScore, " Number Of Clusters:", idx)
```

Output:

```
For n_clusters = 2 The average silhouette_score is : 0.5998398985890973
For n_clusters = 3 The average silhouette_score is : 0.5537982490021037
For n_clusters = 4 The average silhouette_score is : 0.533919415288406
For n_clusters = 5 The average silhouette_score is : 0.460641507207192
For n_clusters = 6 The average silhouette_score is : 0.4685516097102802
For n_clusters = 7 The average silhouette_score is : 0.42313268667935106
For n_clusters = 8 The average silhouette_score is : 0.43283812579237735
For n_clusters = 9 The average silhouette_score is : 0.41602365463779123
Best score : 0.5998398985890973  Number Of Clusters: 2
```

Comment: I know about K-means, you should know the number of clusters beforehand. You provided the code for 3 clusters. The point is to detect the number of clusters and perform clustering automatically. The most close algorithm I could find was DBSCAN.

Comment: @Termos I updated my answer with a method of choosing cluster numbers based on silhouette_score metrics